# specific websites don't respond on Mac

Tags: macos

I'm having a bizarre problem. A client has a website hosted on www.site90.com and my Mac will not load this website: the server keeps timing out. I have tried other devices on the SAME network and everything loads fine. This is unique to my mac; it is not the ISP or the website. This is happening on all browsers, no exceptions.

• I also tried loading the website via a proxy, and that worked to a degree - however, the problem was that certain scripts and forms weren't working.

• I have tried disabling IPv6 - no effect.

• I have tried clearing browsing data - no effect.

Comment: try by IP? maybe your dns server is not healthy.

Comment: do you have any antivirus or other security software installed?